# jQuery draggable and droppable calls MVC action

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am try to implement drag and drop of items into an MVC application, where I drag from `div` to another `div` - this `div` will call a post event, passing in the `data-id`.

I am relatively new to jQuery coding, so I may be missing something very stupid...

**Code**

```
<div id="column1" style="width: 400px; background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li data-id="1">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="column2" style="width: 400px; background-color: black">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $("#column li").draggable({
        revert: true,
        drag: function () {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            var a = $(this).closest("#column").addClass("active");
        },
        stop: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active").closest("#column1").removeClass("active");
        }
    });
</script>
```

The above works fine, it does drag - however my issue is with dropping. Anything that has an ID that contains `Column` should accept drops, I tried to replicate the above for drop, but I do not even get the alert...

```
$("#column").droppable({
    tolerance: "touch",
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        alert('Hello World');
        var targetColumn = $(this),
            move = ui.draggable,
            itemId = move.attr("data-id");
        $.post("Controller/Action", { id: itemId, obj: move });
    }

});
```

Any advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code probably is not working well, because your selector not match any element (you have no element with id `#column`).

You probably want to set a class column and bind to it `draggable` and `droppable` using `.column` as selector.

HTML:

```
<div id="column1" class="column" style="width: 400px; background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)">
    <ul style="list-style-type: none;">
        <li data-id="1"> <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="column2" class="column" style="width: 400px; background-color: black">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
            </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".column li").draggable({
        revert: true,
        drag: function () {
            $(this).addClass("active");
            var a = $(this).closest("#column").addClass("active");
        },
        stop: function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active").closest("#column1").removeClass("active");
        }
    });

    $(".column li").droppable({
        tolerance: "touch",
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            alert('Hello World');
            console.log($(this))

        }

    });
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/CASn4/